# Codeigniter - Access Models And Database on Routing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, content-management-system, codeigniter-3

I'm Planning to make a project in codeigniter 3.0.3 and I want to use routing like below.

1) . www.mydomain.com/categoryNamehere
2) . www.mydomain.com/postNameHere

I have a separate table in my database to keep category names with their unique id's.
What I want is when a user click on a link like www.mydomain.com/xxxxx
      1.first check on category table (xxxxx)
      2. if no match send it (xxxxx) to post controller.
How can I implement this on Codeigniter 3.0.3 ?
I tried to access my models in config / routing.php and also I tried to execute mysql codes (active records) directly in routing page.

Comment: «tried to access my models in config / routing.php and also I tried to execute mysql codes (active records) directly in routing page» - this is very wrong; you shoud create controllers and access models from them.

Comment: @vaviloff  Yes I know. I told that I've tried that way from routing.php file. not from a view. Please read carefully about my requisites

Comment: I didnt say anything about views.

Comment: Of course so if you think we can access controllers from routings.php file , please show how

Comment: Have a look at the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the proposed url structure, we must create one central dispatcher that would

1. Analyze the requested URL.
2. Would query a database to find and display the category.
3. If no category found it would try to find and display the text post.

Sounds like the job for a controller. But how do we make a controller that responds to every request? With the help of wildcard routing!

**application/config/routes.php**

`$route['.*'] = 'default_controller';`

Now every request, regardless of URI, will be routed to `Default_controller.php`.

But how do we write controller without knowing what method will be called? There is a way: the built-in in controller service method `_remap`.

From [the docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html?#remapping-method-calls):

> If your controller contains a method named _remap(), it will always get called regardless of what your URI contains.

So I've let myself fantasize and create a concept Default_controller for you:

**application/controllers/Default_controller.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Default_controller extends CI_Controller {

    // Pseudocode ensues 
    public function _remap()
    {
        // www.mydomain.com/(someTextHere)
        $slug = $this->uri->segment(1);

        $result = $this->load_data($slug);

        echo $result;
    }

    private function load_data($slug)
    {
        // Trying to find a category
        $category = $this->category_model->find($slug);
        if($category !== false)
        {
            // Presumably loads view into buffer
            // and returns it to the calling method
            return $this->load_category($category);
        }

        Trying to find post
        $post = $this->post_model->find($slug);
        if($post !== false)
        {
            return $this->load_post($post);
        }

        // Neither category nor post found
        show_404();
    }

    private function load_category($category)
    {
        // http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data
        return $this->load->view("category", array("category" => $category), true);
    }
}
```

Note: tested this answer on the freshly downloaded [Codeigniter 3.0.3](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/archive/3.0.3.zip)

Comment: It worked for me but I have a small doubt. assume that my load category function and load post function is in a two separate controller files. Is there anyway to call those methods from this file?

Comment: If you're using HMVC in this project then yes, you could call one controller from another. Though it's not best practice. It would be better to place data fetching methods into models and then call those models from any controller your heart desires. If you need more on this please comment.