# Custem URLs inCodeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a URL

```
http://www.example.com/en/category/flowers
```

I want this like below by removing category slug.

```
http://www.example.com/en/flowers
```

here category is flowers

The setting I have on my route config file is

```
$route['en/category/(:any)'] = 'category/view/$1';
```

And I have page urls

```
www.example.com/en/page/categoryname/mypage
```

Need to have in this format by removing "page" slug

```
www.example.com/en/categoryname/test-page
```

The setting is on route config file

```
$route['en/page/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1/$2';
```

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
$route['en/flowers'] = 'page/view/1/3';
```

Here I am asuming that `flowers` category has id 1 and 3 is something else.

Comment: Flowers  is category and i am listing the items under the flowers.

Comment: @lospicos ok noted. I took it like that way.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
$route['en/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'page/view/$1/$2';
$route['en/(:any)'] = 'category/view/$1';
```

Comment: Put it at the end of routes list.

Comment: I have added to the end of route file. That conflicts also with some of the urls which are not stated on route config.

Comment: website is www.ptctour.com

Comment: Follow example I set here. First set more specific routes, then less specific. I.e. `$route['en/category/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'category/view/$1/$2';` has to come before `$route['en/category/(:any)'] = 'category/view/$1';`.

Comment: the main issue fo rme i do not want category or page word in the url. For example $route['en/(:any)'] = 'category/view/$1'; confliclt with www.example.com/en/cart which is not set at route config.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34229664/codeigniter-access-models-and-database-on-routing), maybe that is something you are searching for.